# Checking if points are diagonal

Tags: c#, points

Hello I'm having a little trouble on this one aspect in my code that I'm working on. It deals with points and returns true or not if it's diagonal to other points in my arrayList of Points. Here my code so far:

```
private List<Point> point;

 public void check()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < point.Count; i++)
            {
               validSpot(i);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Here's a hint: how would you do this on paper if you were comparing two points on the X-Y plane? You'd check if the slope equaled a certain value.

Comment: That's a nice way to do it! If you wrote that as an answer I would delete mine.

Comment: oh ok I see what your saying thanks let me write code for it and get back to you in a second

Comment: @Floris: thanks, but I'll let the OP figure it out.

Comment: It's better when you figure it out yourself with just a hint. Good job musical_coder!

Comment: Glad it worked. @Floris: thanks! I used to be a teacher, so giving hints if possible is my style.

Comment: @musical_coder : sorry to hear you _used to be_ a teacher... The world needs more people like you preparing the next generation. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One note, your graph has your y upside down from the way an array stores it.

You could treat your indexes as points on a graph.  To find what falls on the diagonal use slope intercept form.  `y = m x + b`.  Since you only want diagonals, valid slopes are limited to 1 and -1.  Then you just have to define the line that passes through the point of interest and test if the point in question satisfies one of the equations for `m = -1 or m = 1`.  Since the slope is known you only need one point to define the line.

```
public bool func(int[] knownPt,int xTest, int yTest)
{
      //knownPt is int[]{x,y}
      // y = m*x + (yi - xi)
      return yTest== xTest + knownPt[1] - KnownPt[0] || yTest == -xTest +knownPt[1] + KnownPt[0];

 }
```

As a walk through here is `m = -1`

```
 yi = -xi + b

 yi + xi  = b 

 since b = yi + xi

 y = -x + (yi + xi)
```